# Constructing efficient zero knowledge proof card game

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, multiparty-computation, mental-poker

I had asked an unanswered question earlier and now, I think I have an answer (sort of), not really but I think I know where to look for it. We assign each type of card combination a score such that a winning card combination always has a higher score and a tie always have equal score.The two players then play Yao's millionaire's problem to decide who is winner. With mapping known, a player who reveals the secret exponentiations (or cards) and the secret data used to provide his/her input to the problem, one can easily verify that they have shown scores honestly. Which means that the problem is in NP and thus the player should be able to construct zero knowledge proof showing that the score really reflects his card rank without revealing either the cards or the score according to a 1987 paper.That way two players can check who won without actually revealing his/her cards.

Comment: you can put this as an answer under the question you asked. Stack{overflow,exchange} allows you to answer your own question.

Comment: OK thanks, I forgot to give the link of my question